# GetAsTable Issue - Intellibot RPA

Tags: automation, rpa, intellibot, intellibot-robot, intellibot-studio

I am giving input as string on `clipboard` component and I used `getAsTable` after that but it is not working, output is coming `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the usage of the `GetAsTable` component below for your reference.

[image]

There are two input parameters in the `GetAsTable` component, one is `“column separator”` and the other is `“line separator”` which helps in parsing the `clipboard text` into `DataTable` based on the input parameters.
For example, I have copied the below table content from an application and I wanted to get the output as a table then I will use this `GetAsTable` method and provide the separators. Hope this helps!

Clipboard Text (copied text):

[image]

Output Table:

[image]